# Shouldn't the tag be 'shariah' instead of 'sharia'?

Tags: support, tag, tag-synonyms, tag-mistakes

The word is written in Arabic as

## شريعة

Words in Arabic that end with

## ة

should be read with a 'h' in the end if it is read as a single word according to the correct tajweed. So like the tags [sunnah](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sunnah), [dawah](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dawah), [kaabah](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kaabah), etc. shouldn't the correct tag be [shariah](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shariah) instead of [sharia](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sharia)? Or at least, shouldn't [sharia](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sharia) be made a synonym of [shariah](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shariah)?

Answer (score 1):

Both spellings seem to be in use over the net. The Wikipedia uses [Sharia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sharia) and this is also the transliteration used on several other popular sites (like news networks) so I think we should stick with that.

Comment: Also, a synonym isn't that necessary--since they both start the same, one will come up as a suggestion.